# GTA 5 cheats vs. completion

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After completing the main missions, do cheats affect side missions and block getting 100%?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the in game cheats can end up stuck on their activated state prevent the completion of the 100% of the game.

Some cheats like Wanted Up and Wanted Down can lock your game to Never Wanted, so the gold on some missions like [Breach of Contract](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Breach_of_Contract) become impossible. The same goes with Explosive Melee getting stuck and ending up with [Closing the Deal](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Closing_the_Deal) being impossible.

Other ones like Slow Motion and Slow Motion Aim can prevent your game from triggering certain animations because they are messing with the internal game timer.

I can confirm that this happens on versions PS3 1.35, 1.36 and PC 1.44, 1.45, 1.46, 1.47, 1.48.